# How to compare two decimal numbers in bash/awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to compare two decimal values but I am getting errors.
I used

```
if [ "$(echo $result1 '>' $result2 | bc -l)" -eq 1 ];then
```

as suggested by the other Stack Overflow thread.

I am getting errors.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: What are the errors? misspelled one variable name.

Comment: actually the errors are due to some other issues. This works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'decimal values'?  Do you mean integers in base 10, or do you mean strings that represent non-integer real values?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I'm assuming that since the OP is using `bc` especially with `-l` that it's floats that are being compared. The `-l` isn't needed for comparisons though.

Answer (score 50):

You can do it using Bash's numeric context:

```
if (( $(echo "$result1 > $result2" | bc -l) )); then
```

`bc` will output 0 or 1 and the `(( ))` will interpret them as false or true respectively.

The same thing using AWK:

```
if (( $(echo "$result1 $result2" | awk '{print ($1 > $2)}') )); then
```

Comment: +1 for the awk solution, but: `if echo $result1 $result2 | awk '{exit !( $1 > $2)}'; then ...`

Comment: I like to retract my down vote as Dennis's reply is correct with decimal points. For expanded floating point arithmetic using bash, see my reply below.

Comment: @Samir: If you haven't already, you can click again on the down arrow to reverse the downvote.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson It says that my vote is locked and can not be edited unless someone edits this answer.

Comment: +1 @WilliamPursell but using `awk "BEGIN {exit !(${result1} > ${result2})}"` instead of piping echo into awk.

Comment: @CTodea: Values should be passed into AWK using a pipe or the `-v` argument rather than being inserted using shell string interpolation.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Your solution with awk is simple and effective. The best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```
if awk 'BEGIN{exit ARGV[1]>ARGV[2]}' "$z" "$y"
then
  echo z not greater than y
else
  echo z greater than y
fi
```

Comment: To those confused as I was with this, in AWK language, value of boolean statement is 1 if true and 0 if not, oppositely to UNIX shell. So in shell scripts that use above AWK program, one has to revert the result, for example use {exit !(ARGV[1]>ARGV[2])} to get shell exit code corresponding to comparison ARGV[1]>ARGV[2].

Answer (score 8):

```
if [[ `echo "$result1 $result2" | awk '{print ($1 > $2)}'` == 1 ]]; then
  echo "$result1 is greater than $result2"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Following up on Dennis's reply:

Although his reply is correct for decimal points, bash throws *(standard_in) 1: syntax error* with floating point arithmetic.

```bash
result1=12
result2=1.27554e-05


if (( $(echo "$result1 > $result2" | bc -l) )); then
    echo "r1 > r2"
else
    echo "r1 < r2"
fi
```

This returns incorrect output with a warning although with an exit code of 0.

> (standard_in) 1: syntax error
> r1 < r2

While there is no clear solution to this (discussion [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8654051/1243763) and [thread 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137110/28675)), I used following partial fix by rounding off floating point results using `awk` followed by use of `bc` command as in Dennis's reply and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424780/1243763)

Round off to a desired decimal place: Following will get recursive directory space in TB with rounding off at the second decimal place.

```
result2=$(du -s "/home/foo/videos" | tail -n1 | awk '{$1=$1/(1024^3); printf "%.2f", $1;}')
```

You can then use bash arithmetic as above or using `[[ ]]` enclosure as in [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424780/1243763).

```
if (( $(echo "$result1 > $result2" | bc -l) )); then
    echo "r1 > r2"
else
    echo "r1 < r2"
fi
```

or using `-eq` operator where `bc` output of 1 is *true* and 0 is *false*

```
if [[ $(bc <<< "$result1 < $result2") -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "r1 < r2"
else
    echo "r1 > r2"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For shell script I couldn't use double brackets (()). So, what helped me was to split it in two rows and do the comparison in the classic way.

```
low_limit=4.2
value=3.9
        
result=$(echo "${value}<${low_limit}" | bc)
    
if [ $result = 1 ]; then
  echo too low; 
else 
  echo not too low; 
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also `echo` an `if...else` statement to `bc`.

```
- echo $result1 '>' $result2
+ echo "if (${result1} > ${result2}) 1 else 0"

(
#export IFS=2  # example why quoting is important
result1="2.3" 
result2="1.7" 
if [ "$(echo $result1 '>' $result2 | bc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then echo yes; else echo no;fi
if [ "$(echo "if (${result1} > ${result2}) 1 else 0" | bc -l)" -eq 1 ];then echo yes; else echo no; fi
if echo $result1 $result2 | awk '{exit !( $1 > $2)}'; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't bash force type conversion? For example:

```
($result1 + 0) < ($result2 + 0)
```

Comment: `()` construct runs the enclosed text as a command, it doesn't do any arithmetic.  Looks like you are confusing it with the `((...))` operator.

Answer (score -3):

Why use bc ?

```
for i in $(seq -3 0.5 4) ; do echo $i ; if [[ (( "$i" < 2 )) ]] ; then echo "... is < 2";fi; done
```

The only problem : the comparison "<" doesn't work with negative numbers : they are taken as their absolute value.

Comment: `<` inside `[[...]]` is for string comparison (so `20` is less than `3`, and `0.2` is less than `1e-50`). The `(`'s are redundant, you can add as many as you want, they're only for grouping.