# Multiple conditions in an if statement in bash not working

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I created this small bash script to download repos for me. However if statement are not evaluating it properly....I tried many different variation but it just don't work.

```
os=$(lsb_release -si)
version=$(lsb_release -sr)
arch = `getconf LONG_BIT`
if [[$os = 'CentOs' && $version >= '6.0' && $arch = '64']]
then
    echo "Works fine"
    echo $version 
    echo $os 
fi
```

Just as as info: Both `echo $os` & `echo $version` work fine OUTSIDE if statements.

Update : Output of bash -x test.sh

```
++ lsb_release -si
+ os=CentOS
++ lsb_release -sr
+ version=6.4
++ getconf LONG_BIT
+ arch=64
+ [[ CentOS = \C\e\n\t\O\s ]]
```

Comment: Do not destroy the question by rewriting it so that it only contains the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
arch = `getconf LONG_BIT`
```

should be:

```
arch=`getconf LONG_BIT`
```

or better:

```
arch=$(getconf LONG_BIT)
```

You can't use spaces around assignments in `bash`.  What you wrote executed a command called `arch` with arguments `=` and the output from `getconf LONG_BIT` (presumably 32 or 64).

You also need to keep command names (such as `[[`) separate from the arguments, in general.  So, you need to change this:

```
if [[$os = 'CentOs' && $version >= '6.0' && $arch = '64']]
```

so it has spaces around the 'command' name (after the `[[` and before the `]]`):

```
if [[ $os = 'CentOs' && $version >= '6.0' && $arch = '64' ]]
```

I'd probably enclose the variables in double quotes, but it isn't 100% necessary.  Then there's the problem that `[[` does not support the `<=` or `>=` operators (anyone know why not?).  So, you have to use negated logic:

```
if [[ $os = 'CentOs' && ! ($version < '6.0') && $arch = '64' ]]
```

Be careful.  Attach the `!` to the `($version < '6.0')` and you get 'event not found' (if I wanted a sea shell, I'd go to the sea shore; I wish they'd leave historical C shell notations out of `bash`).

```
os=$(lsb_release -si)
version=$(lsb_release -sr)
arch=$(getconf LONG_BIT)
if [[ $os = 'CentOs' && ! ($version < '6.0') && $arch = '64' ]]
then
    echo "Works fine"
    echo "Version $version; OS $os; Arch $arch"
fi
```

Comment: test.sh: line 5: syntax error near `'6.0''
test.sh: line 5: `if [[ $os = 'CentOs' && $version >= '6.0' && $arch = '64' ]]'

Comment: My guess at the lack of string '<=' and '>=': other than for version numbers, you rarely, if ever, need these conditions.

Comment: I copied the snippet you gave me above and i remove version so that i works but i still get no output(no error message)

Comment: I suggest that you add the code from the version you are running to the question, and show the output of `bash -x yourscript.sh` too.  Given: `os=CentOs; version=6.0; arch=64; if [[ $os = 'Centos' && ! ($version < '6.0') && $arch = '64' ]]; then echo Hi; fi`, I get 'Hi' echoed.  What about you?

Comment: I added output of `bash -x yourscript.sh` in main post

Answer (score -1):

To compare floating point numbers in Bash try the following:

```
- if [[$os = 'CentOs' && $version >= '6.0' && $arch = '64']]
+ if [[ $os = 'CentOs' ]] && [[ "$(echo "if (${version} >= 6.0 1 else 0" | bc)" -eq 1 ]] && [[ $arch = '64' ]]
```

See: [How to compare two decimal numbers in bash/awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237794/how-to-compare-two-decimal-numbers-in-bash-awk/)

Comment: Version numbers that have multiple fields (e.g. 6.0.1) cannot be treated as floating point numbers.