# comparing two decimal numbers in bash

Tags: bash, compare, operator-keyword

I need to compare two numbers in a bash script. I get an integer error. Is there any other methods available?

The format for our builds are YYYY.M or YYYY.MM.

So I need to compare that build 2014.7 (July 2014) is older than 2014.10 (October 2014).

```
 #!/bin/bash

 NEWVER="2014.10";                      # 2014.10
 CURVER=$(head -n 1 /release.ver);      # 2014.7

 if [ $NEWVER > $CURVER ]; then
   echo "this version is new";
 fi
```

Comment: try `-gt` instead of `>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237794/how-to-compare-two-decimal-numbers-in-bash-awk

Comment: @MarcB I have tried that, same error.

Comment: @JohnSmith I have tried the first highest voted answer and it did not result any answer for me.

Comment: @JohnSmith I used this one "if (( $(echo "$result1 > $result2" | bc -l) )); then"

Comment: try this one `if [ "$(echo $result1 '>' $result2 | bc -l)" -eq 1 ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`

Answer (score 0):

The complication is that July is formatted as `2014.7` instead of `2014.07`.  Consequently, floating point arithmetic won't work.  One solution is to separate the year and month information and compare separately:

```
NEWVER="2014.10"
CURVER=2014.7
IFS=. read major1 minor1 <<<"$NEWVER"
IFS=. read major2 minor2 <<<"$CURVER"
[[ $major1 -gt $major2 || ($major1 -eq $major2 && $minor1 -gt $minor2) ]] && echo newer
```

#### Alternative

Alternatively, we can fix the month format and then do floating point comparison:

```
fix() { echo "$1" | sed 's/\.\([0-9]\)$/.0\1/'; }
NEWVER=$(fix "$NEWVER")
CURVER=$(fix "$CURVER")
(( $(echo "$NEWVER > $CURVER" | bc -l) )) && echo newer
```

Answer (score 0):

The only standard utility I know of which has a version comparison operation is Gnu `sort`, which implements version comparison as an extension, using option `-V`. (That doesn't mean there aren't any other ones; just that I can't think of any). With Gnu `sort`, the following is possible:

```
key=$CURVER$'\n'$NEWVER
if [[ $key = $(sort -V <<<"$key") ]]; then
  # NEWVER is newer or the same
else
  # NEWVER is older
fi
```