# Bash/Linux - Compare decimal numbers in a script, data from a .csv column

Tags: bash, csv, decimal, comparator

I am trying to compare the decimal numbers in a column one by one. These comparisons are made with respect to constants.

I want to count the number of times the condition is true. But this part is ok.

**The file with the data is a csv separated by ";" and the decimals are separated by a "."**

I have the following code, but I have not achieved anything.

```
fixed_acidity_filter=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {if($1>0 && $1<15) ]{print}}' winequality-white_sincabecera.csv | wc -l)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Does [How to compare two decimal numbers in Bash/Awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237794/) or [How to compare two floating point numbers in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654051/) answer your question?

Comment: @Alorher, probably typo, but you have syntax error in your code in question. And BTW, there are better tools for your task than awk. You probably know.

Answer (score 1):

```
# concept
echo -e "20\n10\n18\n15\n13\n21" | awk '{if($1>0 && $1<15) print $1}'
# your code
echo -e "20;10\n10;10\n18;10\n15;10\n13;10\n21;10" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} {if($1>0 && $1<15) print $1}' | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it doesn' work. And I don't understand this part of the code "echo -e "20;10\n10;10\n18;10\n15;10\n13;10\n21;10". 
Thanks again

Comment: Try in terminal and you will understand. It just simulates your input.